# Choosing H0 and Ha in hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

There seems to be some ambiguity or contradiction in how to correctly choose the null and alternative hypotheses, both online and in my instructor's notes. I'm trying to figure out if this stems merely from my lack of understanding or if there actually is a disagreement in the scientific community at large.
I've seen the following two ideas on choosing H0 and Ha

1. The null hypothesis is the status quo, the state of things already accepted and/or shown to be true by previous data. We assume it to be true and need convincing evidence to reject it. The alternative hypothesis is the one being proposed based on data from the experiment in question, and is assumed to be false unless the data supporting it can convincingly show otherwise.
2. The null hypothesis is always the one that includes the equality, and the alternative hypothesis is the complement to it. It doesn't matter whether the equality is the status quo or is being claimed by the researcher, it is always H0.

An example I made up myself for demonstrative purposes, I'm not looking for an actual solution. Only interested in the hypotheses:

> A researcher believes that children in economically disadvantages areas are more likely to be raised in single-parent homes. He surveys 1000 children from such an area and finds that 317 of them are raised in a single-parent home. Can we conclude with 95% confidence that 30% or more of the children in economically disadvantages areas are raised in single-parent homes?

What would be the H0 and Ha in this case and why?
My professor provided the correct answer (for an equivalent question but with different numbers) to be

> H0 : p >= 0.3; Ha : p < 0.3

With the rationale that H0 must include the equality, which in this case is `greater or equal to 30%`. Her solution then `failed to reject the null hypothesis` and concluded that the researcher's claim is therefore correct.
To me this seems like assuming the claim to be true to begin with and giving it the benefit of the doubt, which is the opposite of what I thought was the correct approach.

A professor in this related question [Difference between "at least" and "more than" in hypothesis testing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987891/difference-between-at-least-and-more-than-in-hypothesis-testing) seemingly took the same approach.

I wish I could talk to my professor about this, but unfortunately there's a significant language barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Your null hypothesis is $H_0:p=0.3$

The alternative hypothesis is $H_1:p>0.3$

You need to calculate $$p(X\geq317)$$ using $X\sim Bin(1000,0.3)$

Can you finish?

Just to clarify:

1. The null hypothesis always has an equal sign and never an inequality symbol
2. In this particular example we conclude that $317$ is not in the critical region.

We conclude that in accepting the null hypothesis there is insufficient evidence that the probability is more than $30$%

Comment: The question is purely hypothetical, this isn't an actual homework assignment. I'm trying to understand the overall strategy of picking the null and alternative hypotheses. If you check the related question, you'll see that a professor would have picked `H1 : p < 0.3` instead. Why?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to choose this alternative hypothesis, since 317 is greater than the mean, we should be looking in the upper part of the distribution, not the lower

Comment: please see my additional comments to my previous answer.

Comment: The way my professor explained it in class, we have two hypotheses: `p >= 0.3` (since the question states "30% or more") and `p < 0.3` as the complement. We must pick the one that has an equality as the null hypothesis, and the other one as the alternative.

Comment: The null hypothesis always states a particular value, in this case $0.3$. The alternative hypothesis is always either $<$ or $>$ or $\neq$

Answer (score 0):

Both ideas of the null and alternative hypothesis are true. The null hypothesis must always include an equals sign, whether it be $\geq\text{, } \leq\text{,  or  just}=$. Usually, however, it's just $=$. The alternative hypothesis is what we wish to show.

The null hypothesis in this case is that the proportion of children in economically disadvantaged areas raised in single-parent homes is $30$%.

The alternative hypothesis is that the proportion of children in economically disadvantaged areas raised in single-parent homes is **greater than** $30$%.

More formally

$$H_0 : p=0.3$$

$$H_a : p \gt 0.3$$

There are two ways you can test this hypothesis if you so wish. Letting $X$ be the number of children raised in single-parent homes, you can use normal approximation to the binomial:

$$P(X\geq317)=1-P(X\lt317)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{316.5-300}{\sqrt{1000\cdot0.3\cdot0.7}}\right)$$

where I used a continuity correction

In R statistical software

```
> 1-pnorm((316.5-300)/sqrt(1000*.3*.7))
[1] 0.1274333
```

You could also, using software, find the exact probability using the standard binomial distribution:

$$P(X\geq317)=\sum_{k=317}^{1000} {1000 \choose k}\cdot0.3^k\cdot0.7^{1000-k}$$

```
> sum(dbinom(317:1000,1000,.3))
[1] 0.1277011
```

Since $n$ is large, the normal approximation does very well.

At $\alpha=0.05$ we fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: You choice is also the one I would have gone with, since for a continuous distribution >= 30% and >30% are the same thing. However, both my professor, and the professor in the linked related question, picked `H0 : p = 0.3; H1 : p < 0.3`. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to choose $H_a$ so that the sample’s estimation fulfills $H_a$.

The reason is that otherwise the rejection rule will always vote for $H_0$ as in the incorrect choice of your professor.

In your case you want to test a probability against $0.3$, the sample’s estimation was $0.37$, hence $H_a\colon p>0.3$ as $0.37>0.3$.  And it does in no way matter where the equal-sign occurs as long as you’re dealing with continuous random variables.

Comment: Why should we choose the alternative according to the observede data?